# facing problem while running reg.predict in jupyter ntbk says "ValueError"

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Trying to learn sklearn in python. But the jupyter ntbk is giving error saying "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=750.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."
*But I have already defined x to be 2D array using x.values.reshape(-1,1)

**You can find the CSV file and screenshot of the Error Code here -> https://github.com/CaptainRD/CSV-for-StackOverflow**

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    sns.set()

    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    data = pd.read_csv('1.02. Multiple linear regression.csv')
    data.head()
    x = data[['SAT','Rand 1,2,3']]
    y = data['GPA']
    reg = LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(x,y)r2 = reg.score(x,y)
    n = x.shape[0]
    p = x.shape[1]

    adjusted_r2 = 1-(1-r2)*(n-1)/(n-p-1)
    adjusted_r2
    reg.predict(1750)
```

Comment: could you please add your code too? It's kind of hard to help you now.

Comment: Done! Can you have a look again? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your code, your x has two variables, **SAT** and **Rand 1,2,3**. Which means, you need to provide a **two dimensional input** for your predict method. example:

```
reg.predict([[1750, 1]])
```

which returns:

```
>>> array([1.88])
```

You are facing this error because you did not provide the second value (for the **Rand 1,2,3** variable). Note, if this variable is not important, you should remove it from your x data.

Answer (score 0):

This model is mapping two inputs (`SAT` and `Rand 1,2,3`) to a single output (`GPA`), and thus requires a list of two elements as input for a valid prediction. I'm guessing the `1750` that you're supplying is meant to be the `SAT` value, but you also need to provide the `Rand 1,2,3` value. Something like `[1750, 1]` would work.